# Script to move data between sheets and adding a static date stamp (Google sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script

I need some assistance please. I have a spreadsheet that moves data from one sheet(JDE worklist) to the next (Printed) by clicking the textbox next to the row to be moved. When the tickbox is un-ticked after its moved the first time it moves it to a final sheet (PrintedArchive). This part works fine.

The problem is that I need a static date stamp next to the row once it gets moved to the next sheet as to capture start and end dates. The date can be added to column BE.

If I try and add a separated script to add a date stamp the script for moving the data stops functioning. So is there a way to incorporate this into the script that moves the data?

Please note that don't have much experience and I'm still learning and would really appreciate the help.

This is the script im currently using to move the data

```
function onEdit(event) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "JDE Worklist" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Printed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Printed" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == false) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("PrintedArchive");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);

  

  }
}
```

[Sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i_QJtL0Bdr_xM5JqMO6mLau3w9W5mehV6qcXW1QTqa0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const s = e.range.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "JDE Worklist" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Printed");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).moveTo(trg);
    tsh.getRange("BE" + e.range.rowStart).setValue(new Date());
    s.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  } else if (s.getName() == "Printed" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "FALSE") {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("PrintedArchive");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).moveTo(trg);
    tsh.getRange("BE" + e.range.rowStart).setValue(new Date());
    s.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Initially I thought this worked but it seems to be adding the date stamp in the corresponding row where the original data was copied from leaving open spaces. Between the last copied row and the next.

Comment: I thought you wanted it in the same row  and column BE

Comment: Sorry I might have not explained correctly. I have added a link to a sample spreadsheet. The data moves over the the next sheet without leaving blanks, irrespective of the order in which you tick the boxes. But the date stamp doesn't match it as the stamp seems to line up with the row the data was copied from and not to where it is on the printed sheet.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow links to spreadsheets

Comment: No stress. Unfortunately doesn't seem like i can post a screen of what its doing either.